# Need a macro to search and replace data in XML using VBA

Tags: xml, vba, notepad

I need this help, I tried many ways but not could not figure out.

I have a folder (c:\mydocument) which contains multiple xml files (Lets say 100) and also 1 excel file (name=usermapping" which contains Column A multiple email id (lets say 50)  eg. abc@gmail.com and column b also has different email ids abcdef@gmail.com

I need a VBA code, which will open these xml files and search for email -ids in column A of excel file and replace the xml with Column "B" email ID's.

Any help in this regard would be highly appreciable.  If you need any questions or clarification, please do reply to this message.

Warm regards

Johnny

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Beginners are welcome, but we expect a certain amount of effort to be expended on attempting to solve your own problem prior to a question being posted. We dont write code for you although we are very willing to help you fix issues with code you have written.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you workaround instead of code. Use Power query to get data from XML.
Once you have data then create a calculated column, where you can change/replace.
Now push that data into the table, and create code to save as .xml.

[image]

Comment: I tried this, however while converting this back to XML, codes in xml are changing.  Hence I was looking for some code changes

Comment: More over, I have 100s of files, changing one by one will consume lot of time and effort

Comment: You can refer the folder name power query will combine all files inside the folder.

Comment: and after replacing, can I split the files again back to the folder separately?

Comment: I tried, unfortunately its not working

Comment: You always have a column to identify the file, so you can filter and save as.
I am adding screenshot below see that.

Comment: Possible to upload 2 .xml files?

Comment: How do I upload the files, I'm not seeing an option

Comment: Paste on google drive and post link here.

Comment: I have added screenshot of XML and excel which contains sample email IDs

Comment: It is not possible for me to create files from image.
try sending to me over lkthecool@gmail.com, if it is ok.

Comment: sent to you as mentioned

Comment: I checked the file .xml, it is not valid, it may open on IE but tags are missing.
Closing tag for my:Supervisor, is missing and might be others. It is invalid file for for excel.

Comment: Try to open it using notepad++, you should be able to

Comment: It is quite easy, you have mentioned incorrect subject, I edited answer..

Comment: Can you please send me back these files with code, I will run it in my system and will check and will revert if any questions